# How might one formulate integration over an ordered probability simplex?

Tags: probability, integration, multivariable-calculus, simplex

Given a probability simplex ($x_i \geq 0$, $i=1,\ldots,n$)
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1,
\end{equation}
I want to attempt integrations of various ("operator-monotone"-based https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d393/21f142432eddd2af0d3bd07235a63aca2019.pdf) functions over that subsection for which
\begin{equation}
x_i \geq x_{i-1}.
\end{equation}

Further, I'm particularly interested in such integrations ($n=4$) with the additional ("absolute separability") constraint (eq. (3) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0502170.pdf)
\begin{equation}
x_1 \leq x_3+2 \sqrt{x_2 x_4}.
\end{equation}

What are my options for setting up the integrations (coordinate transformations might be of interest)? The particular integrations I have in mind are seemingly very challenging, and I may (probably) have to resort to numerical methods.

Answer (score 1):

Using the GenericCylindricalDecomposition command of Mathematica, we can express the integral of 1 over the 3-dimensional probability simplex as the sum of three
integrations (for ease of presentation, I replace the subscripted variables $x_i$ by $xi$, $i=1,2,3$)

```
Integrate[1, {x3, 0, 1/4}, {x2, x3, 1/2 (1 - 2 x3)}, {x1, 1 - x2 - 2 x3, 1 - x2 - x3}] + Integrate[1, {x3, 0, 1/4}, {x2, 1/2 (1 - 2 x3), (1 - x3)/2}, {x1, x2, 1 - x2 - x3}] + Integrate[1, {x3, 1/4, 1/3}, {x2, x3, 1/2 (1 - x3)}, {x1, x2, 1 - x2 - x3}]
```

The results of the three integrations are $\left\{\frac{1}{192},\frac{1}{768},\frac{1}{2304}\right\}$, respectively, summing to $\frac{1}{144}$, which is one-twenty-fourth ($\frac{1}{4!}$)of the integration ($\frac{1}{6}$) over the unordered simplex.

It remains now for my investigations to incorporate the absolute separability constraint, 
\begin{equation}
x_1 \leq x_3+2 \sqrt{x_2 x_4},
\end{equation}
into the integrations.